# JS: What is the proper way to count time after starting a timer?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm making a simple reaction timer game. The only thing I'm getting stuck on is counting the time it takes to answer.

Once the prompt for user input displays I'm running this function:

```
var addScore = function () {
    if (playing) {
        setInterval(function () {
            score += 10;
        }, 10)
    }
};
```

So once the player starts playing this function starts and adds 10 to the score after every 10 millisecond. I tried playing and sometimes my score is showing 5 - 7 seconds even if I answer as soon as the answer shows. Is it because I'm adding the time incorrectly?

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/lee45276/f3s6waub/

Answer (score 3):

- Are you `clearInterval`-ing? Because if not, those `setInterval` functions will accumulate, each adding `10` to the score every 10ms or so.
- `setInterval` is not very precise, it could happen that your function gets delayed by more than 10ms. (Not to the point where you're having 10ms turn into 5000ms as in your example, but a bit.) This is a much better idea, no timers involved:

  ```
  var questionPosedTime = new Date();
  poseTheQuestion();
  onAnswerReceived(function() {
    var answerReceivedTime = new Date();
    var answeringDelayInMilliseconds = answerReceivedTime - questionPosedTime;
    adjustScore(answeringDelayInMilliseconds);
  });
  ```

Comment: If precision is required (usually a Date object is sufficient, but if better is available…) there is the [*Navigation Timing* (high precision) API](http://www.sitepoint.com/discovering-the-high-resolution-time-api/). [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing) provides some practical examples.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks. Just be careful if you care about compatibility, it's [not yet universally available](http://caniuse.com/#search=High%20Resolution%20Time%20API).